# Need help converting strtotime() in php

Tags: php

I am trying to sort an array of times in php. I use strtotime to convert strings to times in php and sort times.

```
$temp = strtotime("$year/$month/$day");
```

works for me and I am able to sort time by year/month/day.

But when I tried:

```
$temp = strtotime("$year/$month/$day $h:$m:$s");
```

it did not work when I try to sort time by `year/month/day hour:minute:second`.

Much appreciated if anyone can give me some help.

Comment: Looks to work to me https://3v4l.org/Frv92, you sure your variables are what you think they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If double quotes are not building your string properly, use the `.` instead of double quote concatenation.

```
strtotime($year."/".$month."/".$day." ".$h.":".$m.":".$s);
```

Comment: @user3783243 Honestly I've still got no idea. I tested the code he provided and it does work. This has happened to me once before, I solved it this way. I had less experience then and don't remember how I declared my variables exactly. I suspect the answer as to why his code doesn't  function involves whatever he's using for `$h $m $s` and the way php concatenates double quotes vs the `.` operator?

Comment: Double quotes vs. `.` is the same. With the exception if there were characters next to the variable that made it into an undefined variable. That isn't the case here though https://regex101.com/r/aB8kUe/1/.